# dead.letter containing git information

Tags: git

Today, after working on a project enclosed in a git repository, I found a file called `dead.letter` in my home folder containing the following:

```
From laura Tue Aug  1 14:42:07 2017
Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 14:42:07 -0300
To: laura
User-Agent: mail v14.9.0

Subject: editor saved ``/project/path/.git/addp-hunk-edit.diff''
You were editing the file "/project/path/.git/addp-hunk-edit.diff"
at <Tue Aug  1 14:42> on the machine ``hostname''
when the editor was killed.

You can retrieve most of your changes to this file
using the "recover" command of the editor.
An easy way to do this is to give the command "vi -r /project/path/.git/addp-hunk-edit.diff".
This method also works using "ex" and "edit".
```

`/project/path/.git/addp-hunk-edit.diff` didn't exist.

After a quick search I find that `dead.letter` is created when a mail client cannot send an email. What does git have to do with `dead.letter` and mail clients?

Comment: It is a way of getting information to the user. As you pointed out, a `dead.letter` is create when there is an issue between the email client (`mail`) and server.

Answer (score 1):

`git` doesn't have anything directly to do with the `~/.dead.letter` file. 
 `git` tried to send an email (probably with the `mail`, `mailx`, or `sendmail` command).

That program was unable to send the mail, so stored it in `~/.dead.letter`, which is a standard [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format file, readable with most unix mail clients (e.g. `mutt -f ~/.dead.letter`).

This has been standard behaviour on unix & linux for longer than I can remember - the purpose is to ensure that you don't lose an email message you were editing when you abruptly exit from the email client (because the client crashed or was killed, connection to the machine was lost, etc).

Comment: +1 but I've corrected the last line -- `dead.letter` saves a message draft, not a undelivered message.

Comment: fair enough, but in this particular context, all that can really be said is that the message couldn't be sent - sendmail (or whatever) couldn't deliver the msg for whatever reason (client crash, connection dropped, no local MTA, or one of many other possible reasons) so saves it in `~/.dead.letter`.    AFAICS, there's nothing to suggest that anything crashed.   Given that most linux users today configure their MUAs to use an SMTP smarthost and don't feel the need to have even a light-weight MTA like `msmtp` installed (crazy, i know), i'd guess "missing local MTA" as the probable cause.